# Swift - How to make a cURL request? (Swift 5.2 / macOS Catalina)

Tags: ios, swift, curl

I'm developing a test app on MacOS - intended for the Mac desktop. Looking to make a API call to Gumroad (digital products seller). They say that we have to make a cURL request: like this -

```
curl https://api.gumroad.com/v2/licenses/verify \
  -d "product_permalink=QMGY" \
  -d "license_key=YOUR_CUSTOMERS_LICENSE_KEY" \
  -X POST
```

I'm very new to swift and everything MacOS development. Clueless how I'd do this - lot of documentation is years old or iOS, or talks of other http requests (and I don't know how to relate that to making a cURL call) which makes it hard. Any help is appreciated.

The call returns a JSON in response - I think I can figure that part. Just don't know I'd make this call.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

`curl` is actually an application in unix systems to make network calls.

To make Http calls in Swift, this is what you'll need to do

```swift
// Prepare URL
let url = URL(string: "https://api.gumroad.com/v2/licenses/verify")
guard let requestUrl = url else { fatalError() }

// Prepare URL Request Object
var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl)
request.httpMethod = "POST"

// Set HTTP Request Body
let params = ["product_permalink": "QMGY", "license_key": "YOUR_CUSTOMERS_LICENSE_KEY"]
let jsonData = try? JSONEncoder().encode(params)

request.httpBody = jsonData

// Set HTTP Requst Header
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

// Perform HTTP Request
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
    guard let data = data else {
        // handle no response failure
    }

    print("data: \(String(describing: String(bytes: data, encoding: .utf8)))")
    guard error == nil else {
        // handle network error
    }
    do {
        // decode json data
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let object = try decoder.decode(DATA_TYPE, from: data) // <= substitute DATA_TYPE

        // handle success

    } catch let error {
        // handle json decoding error
    }
}
task.resume()
```